# Cognos 8 Introduction

Tags: business-intelligence, cognos

Being a programmer who likes all things terminal (like Vim and the GNU tools), I've finally met my match. The company I work for has decided to move from an in-house developed report generator to the Cognos suite.

We have had some informal meetings/workshops regarding the process of creating reports in Cognos, but I can't really make it stick on my non-GUI brain.

Does anyone know of any nice introductions or tutorial style documents explaining how to create projects in the Framework Manager and reports in Report Studio?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Better practice your mouse-moving muscles. :)

I came across [this presentation](http://www.slideshare.net/dwiner/cognos-report-net-training-244734?src=related_normal&rel=1230393), it is for Reportnet which is a pre-cursor to Cognos 8 but it is high-level enough to give you an accurate overview of how stuff works in Cognos.

There's a lot of content on [IBM Developerworks](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/data/community/#cognos)

I really think you will like the old [Cognos Multimedia Knowledge Base](http://support.cognos.com/supported/en/support/rmkb/Multimedia_Knowledge_Base.html). They have stopped developing content for it (last C8 content is for version 8.1) but for an intro it will serve you well. Look at the Reportnet Stuff too, it is older but you will get a feel for "how stuff works" in Cognos.

Comment: Thanks! That presentation was really helpful for understanding the "big picture". I also found some documentation in "C:\Program Files (x86)\cognos\c8.4\webcontent\documentation" (depending on installation).